# How to properly define a new admonition in Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docutils

With Sphinx it is easy to write extensions, but is it very hard to extend Sphinx in the proper way.

I would like to define a custom Admonition so I have:

```
class exercise(nodes.Admonition, nodes.Element):
    pass

class ExerciseDirective(BaseAdmonition):
    node_class = exercise

def visit_exercise(self, node, name=''):
    self.visit_admonition(node, 'exercise')

def depart_exercise(self, node=None):
    self.depart_admonition(node)

def setup(app):
    app.add_directive('exercise', ExerciseDirective)

    app.add_node(exercise,
        html=(visit_exercise, depart_exercise)
    )
```

Unfortunately this is not enough because my `exercise` have no title. I noticed the translations for admonitions is on `docutils/languages` which can be later read with `language.labels`. As my label `exercise` is not defined, I have no text.

A correct way would be to add a new label for the defined language. I do not know how....

One **very** ugly solution would be to hack the hardcoded `admonitionlabels`:

```
sphinx.locale.admonitionlabels['exercise'] = 'Exercise'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also manually do what the base `visit_admonition` does and add the title node yourself:

```
def visit_exercise(self, node, name=''):
    self.visit_admonition(node, 'exercise')
    if not isinstance(node[0], nodes.title):
        node.insert(0, nodes.title('exercise', _('Exercise')))
```

I used `_('Exercise')` as an example, but you could also put just `'Exercise'` if you have no intentions of localization.

Comment: Well, I could do this, but this is also a very ugly hack not [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) at all :(

Comment: I think you will find that is often the case when extending Sphinx, unfortunately.

Comment: Sadly I am starting to realize that :(